# Channel messaging:${this.cid} hasn't been initialized yet. Make sure to call .watch() and wait for it to resolve

Tags: reactjs

I am integrating https://getstream.io/ with my application. It has some list of users and when I switch the user to check chat for that particular user it gives me error as "Channel messaging:${this.cid} hasn't been initialized yet. Make sure to call .watch() and wait for it to resolve".

After setting user and channel I return  component with specified channel.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Have you got the answer ? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This getstream error simply means that by the time you are switching to a new user to get their messages, you are not providing that `channel's` id to getstream to fetch the user's messages.

When you switch to retrieve that user's chat, make sure that your provide the `channel's id` the user belongs to. Are you using React or which frontend library are you using. For example using React you may have:

```
const ChatChannel = ({
   auth: {
    user: { accountId, cToken, username, profilePicUrl },
  },
  match: {
    params: { channelId },
  },
  onGetChannelsRequest
}) => {
  const [chatClient, setChatClient] = useState(null);
  const userToken = cToken;
  let channel;

  useEffect(() => {
    const initChat = async () => {
      const client = StreamChat.getInstance('yourApiKey');

      await client.connectUser(
        {
          id: accountId,
          name: username
          image: profilePicUrl,
        },
        userToken,
      );

      setChatClient(client);
    };

    initChat();
  }, []);

  channel = chatClient && chatClient.channel('messaging', channelId);

  if (!chatClient) {
    return <LoadingIndicator />;
  }

  return (
      <section>
        <Chat client={chatClient} theme="messaging light">
          <Channel channel={channel}>
            <Window>
              <MessageList />
              <MessageInput />
            </Window>
            <Thread />
          </Channel>
        </Chat>
      </section>
  );
};
```

So when switching to a particular chat, you can use React-router for instance to pass to getStream the `channel's id` from the `match.params props` if you wish. This way, as long as geStream has not initialized the channel and retrieved its messages, the loading indicator will keep showing.

Hope it helps though.